# How to create responsive menu that drops-down on TOP of hero content (Tailwind CSS...)

Tags: css, responsive-design, tailwind-css

I'm working on a site ( my first using tailwind CSS) and I snagged & adjusted some code for the nav bar.

Take a look at it live here: -- REDACTED

The nav bar looks great to me on desktop, and on the drop down for mobile EXCEPT I'd like to make the menu drop down on TOP of the hero content rather than pushing it down.

It's been a while since I wrote CSS, but I think part of the problem could be related to how I'm using flexbox in this current version.  My memory makes me think I've got to do some tweaking with `position: absolute` & `position: relative` , but I can't figure out what I need to do here :/

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set the sub-menu CSS to position absolute so it doesn't affect any content on the page and have its parent be in position relative.

**CSS**

```
nav{
    position:relative;
}

#nav-content{
    position:absolute;
    top:58px; /*Your navigation height*/
    background-color:#FFF;
    left:0px;        
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that in principle.

In the current setup, this breaks my layout; it removes the navigation from the flexbox alignment it has for desktop, in addition to removing itself from the white header.

Comment: It shouldn't affect your desktop navigation if you add the code in media queries which only targets screens under 1024px (mobile version of the menu).

`@media (max-width: 1024px){}`